# RN42 Bluetooth HID KEYBOARD sketch by silverball

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-pro-mini

How can I use **RN42** sketch by silverball

```
/*
  RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino.cpp - Roving Netowrks RN42 Bluetooth HID raw library
  Developed by Chris Leitner - 2012

  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
  Lesser General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
  
  RN42 HID raw report format:
  |start(1 byte)|length(1 byte)|descriptor(1 byte)|data(length - 1 [for the descriptor])
  Keyboard:
  |0xFD|9|1|modifier|0x00|code 1|code 2|code 3|code 4|code 5|code 6
  Keyboard modifier bits (sent as one byte)
  bit 7     |bit 6      |bit 5      |bit 4  |bit 3  |bit 2  |bit 1      |bit 0
  rt GUI    |rt alt     |rt shift   |rt ctrl|lt GUI |lt alt |lt shift   |lt ctrl
  
  You must initialize the Serial library in your code before you call any of these functions.
  The default speed for the RN42 is 115200 - add this in the setup function Serial.begin(115200);
  */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino.h"

RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino::RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino(){
}

//Sends a raw report for a keyboard HID
void RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino::SendKeyboardRaw(char raw_data[], uint8_t mod_bit){

    //write the RN42 Keyboard raw header
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0xFD); //start byte indicator for RN42
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x09); //length of the raw report (how many bytes)
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x01); //descritptor byte see the RN42 HID manual for details 0x01 is keyboard
    Serial.write((uint8_t)mod_bit); //modifier bit (indicates shift, control, and other keys (see comments above)
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00); //unused always send 0x00
    //write the key press data
    //each of these should be an ASCII keycode indicating a keypressed
    //example 0x04 is an 'a' see the RN42 HID manual for a list of codes
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[0]);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[1]);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[2]);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[3]);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[4]);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)raw_data[5]);
}

//This function just send a raw report with no keys or modifiers pressed
void RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino::SendKeyboardRawBlank(void){
    
    //write the RN42 Keyboard raw header
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0xFD);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x09);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x01);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    //write the key press data
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x00);
}

//Sends a raw report for a gamepad
void RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino::SendGamepadRaw(char x_left, char y_left, char z_pos, char rot_pos, uint8_t buttons1, uint8_t buttons2)
{
    //write the header part for RN42
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0xFD); //start byte
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x06); //length of the descriptor
    //gampad positions and buttons
    //on a gamepad there typically is two analog joysticks one is typically used to
    //indicate x/y position and one is for z/rotation. 
    Serial.write((uint8_t)x_left); //value between -127 to 127 indicating the x postition
    Serial.write((uint8_t)y_left); //value between -127 to 127 indicating the y postition
    Serial.write((uint8_t)z_pos); //value between -127 to 127 indicating the z postition
    Serial.write((uint8_t)rot_pos); //value between -127 to 127 indicating the rotation postition
    //one bit for each button pressed there can be a total of 16 buttons one byte in each
    //set the bit to show a button pressed and clear the bit to indicate not pressed
    Serial.write((uint8_t)buttons1); 
    Serial.write((uint8_t)buttons2);
}

void RN42_HIDRaw_Arduino::SendMouseRaw(uint8_t buttons, uint8_t x_stop, uint8_t y_stop, uint8_t wheel){
    //write the header part for RN42
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0xFD);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x05);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)0x02);
    //gampad positions and buttons
    Serial.write((uint8_t)buttons);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)x_stop);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)y_stop);
    Serial.write((uint8_t)wheel);
}
```

And act Like Keyboard.h do ? just simply putting `keyboard.press;`

JUst noob question.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: You see when you  put on your code this sample keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_ARROW) it actually does that key on keyboard. But you cant do that if you're using Bluetooth module (unless your using ESP32). Im using RN42 and i want to do the same function as keyboard.h does. Ive been searching for 2 weeks and i stumbled upon that sketch above saying that it is keyboard sketch for RN42. But i dont know how it actually put on my sketch like keyboard.h does.

Comment: are you saying that you want to use the RN42 as a USB keyboard?

Comment: no, what i'm saying is, I want it to act as keyboard. I know its RN42 cant act as USB Keyboard thats why im searching for BLE Keyboard sketch. And silverball says that this code can act as keyboard

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243602/arduino-rn-42-bluetooth-module-hid

He says in this question. But didnt say how to use it. Im begginer at arduino and Im connecting RN42 to my Arduino Pro Mini. I want the RN42 to send a data that read in computer like you press a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using an Arduino, I recommend you to use the BPlib, it's a free arduino library that contains functions that are similar to the Keyboard.h.

The following link is from the Arduino website: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/bplib/

When you download the Lib, take a look at the examples given by the creator of the Library, all the example code have the explanation of each funcition used, and you can also check for some documentation online. I hope that this help you!